# What does it mean for a film to be cruel, according to Roger Ebert?

Tags: analysis, irreversible

Roger Ebert starts his review (see https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/irreversible-2003) of Gaspar Noé's film *Irréversible* as follows:

> "Irreversible" is a movie so violent and cruel that most people will find it unwatchable.

What does it mean for a film to be cruel, according to Roger Ebert? Toward the end of the review Ebert also states that the film "shows such cruelty", but it seems he is not equating a film being cruel and a film showing cruelty. I am not asking why Ebert thinks the film *Irréversible* specifically is cruel, as he describes exactly this in the review, one could say, although an answer focusing on *Irréversible* could also be valuable.

As a side note, observe that the much broader question "What does it mean for a film to be cruel?" is also very interesting. As there is already plenty of opinion pieces, books and papers available and I have yet to read them, I am not asking this broader question at the moment. But as far as I understand roughly speaking there are at least two distinct strands one could a priori decide to pursue. One is to interpret "cruelty" matter-of-factly, e.g. if animals are harmed in the making of a film (e.g. see the interview of Tarkovsky available at [https://web.archive.org/web/20120813182721/http://people.ucalgary.ca/~tstronds/nostalghia.com/TheTopics/PassionacctoAndrei.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120813182721/http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Etstronds/nostalghia.com/TheTopics/PassionacctoAndrei.html) where the related parts in his film *Andrei Rublev* are discussed briefly). And the other is to implicitly make the case that whatever it could mean for a film to be cruel, it ought to be an extension of what it means for theater to be cruel, as outlined and advocated for by Antonin Artaud. It seems to me neither of these approaches are fully satisfactory.

Comment: Folks are VTC as "opinion-based," but this question specifically asks for Roger Ebert's opinion, which is something that could be definitively answered by appealing to Ebert's voluminous writings.

Comment: Before I read the article, I assumed that Ebert meant that the film seemed to expect the audience to take an unwholesome pleasure in watching cruel behavior, that it was entertainment for cruel people. But now, having read the article, my take is nearly opposite: the film was being cruel to the audience in subjecting us to such an unpleasant experience.

Answer (score 0):

A film can't be cruel.  A film can't be emotional, as it's merely celluloid and devoid of feeling.  However, the *contents* of said movie can be cruel.  It can elicit a feeling of cruelty, or can contain acts of cruelty.

Ebert merely left out some assumed words in his review.  Sometimes you don't need to write every word literally to get a point across.  So, in effect, Ebert wrote:

> "Irreversible" is a movie (with imagery) so violent and cruel that most people will
> find it unwatchable.

Comment: I think makes perfect sense to describe a film as having some agency over the viewer, such as a comedy that relies on cringe/awkwardness as "offering no relief" or "turning the screws" or something like that. Obviously the film is not sentient, but the people who made it are, and we can recognise that in how we speak about films.

Comment: Yeah, there are plenty of films that contain cruelty but wouldn't be described as "cruel" because of the way that cruelty is framed. In fact, the linked review explains this pretty clearly: *"The camera looks on unflinchingly as [describes acts of violence and cruelty] for several long, unrelenting minutes ... a stationary-camera shot that goes on and on and never cuts away ... It starts with it, and asks us to sit there for another hour and process our thoughts"* - it's a "cruel" film because it portrays the cruelty in such an "unflinching", "unrelenting" way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I don't think your answer answers my question. It seems you declared your position on the matter, which I find valuable independently of the question I'm asking. Or else what I would find helpful is if you could justify, based on other writings of Ebert (or the same interview), why he merely left out some words.

Comment: Further, it might be the case that you got Ebert's point precisely, but since I am asking about it I think it would be fair to say that for the purposes of this question it would be better to go more in depth.

Comment: However I agree that the "is" in "this film is cruel" is doing a lot of heavy lifting, and that an answer ought to try to engage with this heavy lifting.

Comment: you are being superbly pedantic.  You are being so specific to say the actual media upon which the movie was shot should not be confused with the contents.  When colloquially people always refer to a movie as "the film".  Flick, film, movie.  They are all the same.